# How to set set default value of the Suneditor formats dropdown to Header1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, suneditor

https://codesandbox.io/s/suneditor-react-forked-w594x3?file=/src/App.js:781-788

Into the above mentioned link I have added below mentioned format.

```
formats: ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
```

It is showing multiple header options in the format dropdown. I wanted to know how I can set default value of the dropdown to Header1

Currently on default it is showing as below
[image]

but need to setup it as below

[image]